# Do Wireless Cards in Managed Mode Really Accepts Beacon Frames?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I am a newbie in Wireless Terminology. My question is Do Wireless Card Really Accepts Beacon Frames while being in Managed Mode. If i open my Wireless Settings and look for Wireless Networks. It definitely shows me the Networks around me which clearly states that Wireless Card is intercepting the Beacon Frames. But when i sniff the traffic with Wireshark. It shows me Beacon Frames were never intercepted actually. So basically, my question how do Wireless Card identify the Wireless Networks around a user in managed mode?

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: Wireshark won't show you anything unless: #1 you are connected or #2 your card is operating in "Promiscuous mode".

Comment: My question isn't about Wireshark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, wireless clients receive Beacons all the time, whether scanning or not, and whether or not they're configured to be clients of an infrastructure AP (which is what I think you mean by "managed mode").

Wireless clients scan for networks using a mix of active and passive scanning techniques. Active scans involve tuning to each channel in turn, transmitting Probe Requests and listening for Probe Responses. Active scans are preferred as you can usually get all your responses in just a few milliseconds per channel and can move on quickly. Passive scans involve tuning to each channel in turn and passively listening for Beacons. However, since most APs only send one Beacon every 100ms or so, it requires at least 100ms per channel, which can make full scans of all 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz channels take several seconds total, which is a long time to make the user wait.

Please note that Beacon frames are not ACK'd, and Beacon frames don't show up in sniffer traces unless you place the interface in 802.11 Monitor Mode. So if you ran Wireshark and didn't see any Beacons at all, you probably didn't put your interface in 802.11 Monitor Mode. Or if you saw the Beacons but thought they weren't being received successfully because you never saw them get ACK'd, you just had a misconception about how 802.11 works and those frames probably were indeed being received successfully by all clients in range.